# Spring CrossOrigin issue: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header is present on the requested resource returning 401 as HTTP response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I have an API which takes two header ACCESS_TOKEN and TIME_OF_CALL as well as input parameter as mentioned below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pay/capture", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "ACCESS_TOKEN,TIME_OF_CALL", origins = "*")
public ResponseEntity<?> fetchRazorPayDetails(@RequestParam("id") Long id) 
{/***logics here*/}
```

hitting this API from local host is returning 401 saying

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://soandsoURL , response to preflight doesn't pass access control. check No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header is present on the requested resource. origin 'http://localhost:1234' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401
```

even though i had clearly annotated with

> @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "ACCESS_TOKEN,TIME_OF_CALL", origins = "*")

to accept all origin and two of the mentioned header. Am I missing something?
 or values to allowedHeaders can't be comma separated? Any help on this issue 
 will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the issue was with Options(unauthorised 401 was the error), PFA screenshot.[image]

It was just because I was declaring/adding options with @CrossOrigin. earlier it was `

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pay/capture", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "ACCESS_TOKEN,TIME_OF_CALL", origins = "*")
public ResponseEntity<?> fetchRazorPayDetails(@RequestParam("id") Long id) 
{/***logics here*/}`
```

I removed optional parameter from @CrossOrigin and simply kept as

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pay/capture", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<?> fetchRazorPayDetails(@RequestParam("id") Long id) 
    {/***logics here*/}
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom filter as bellow :

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with, authorization");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this in your custom filter class:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = this.getAsHttpRequest(req);
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse=this.getAsHttpResponse(res);
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with, authorization, ACCESS_TOKEN, TIME_OF_CALL");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);

}

private HttpServletResponse getAsHttpResponse(ServletResponse response)
{
    if (!(response instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Expecting an HTTP request");
    }

    return (HttpServletResponse) response;
}

private HttpServletRequest getAsHttpRequest(ServletRequest request)
{
    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Expecting an HTTP request");
    }

    return (HttpServletRequest) request;
}
```

And In the WebSecurity class do like this. It will work

```
//To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser 
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}
```